# Daily DATETIME of MIN MAX in same row in an adjacent column

Tags: mysql

Looking for a way for this query that I have written to display the actual DATETIME that the MIN & MAX temperature occurred at for that day in the same row in an adjacent column.

I have been searching and trying a few things, but I am a bit lost with joins, which I assume you need to use for this.

Current query and result..

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(tstLocal) AS "YEAR", 
    MONTHNAME(tstLocal) AS "MONTH", 
    DAY(tstLocal) AS "DAY",
    min(tempC) AS "DAILY MIN TEMP", 
    max(tempC) AS "DAILY MAX TEMP",  
    ROUND(AVG(tempC),1) AS "DAILY AVG TEMP"
FROM 
    house.outside1
WHERE 
    YEAR(tstLocal) = '2014' AND MONTH(tstLocal) = '7'
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(tstLocal),
    MONTH(tstLocal),
    DAY(tstLocal);
```

[image: RESULTS]

What do I need to do to display it with the DATETIME that these MIN / MAX temperatures occurred at?

Comment: why are you splitting up the datetime (into year,month,day) instead of using it straight in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are already using a `group by`, the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick will work:

```
SELECT YEAR(tstLocal) AS "YEAR", MONTHNAME(tstLocal) AS "MONTH", DAY(tstLocal) AS "DAY",
       min(tempC) AS "DAILY MIN TEMP", max(tempC) AS "DAILY MAX TEMP",
       ROUND(AVG(tempC),1) AS "DAILY AVG TEMP",
       substring_index(group_concat(tstlocal order by tempC asc), ',', 1) as min_datetime,
       substring_index(group_concat(tstlocal order by tempC desc), ',', 1) as max_datetime
FROM house.outside1
WHERE  YEAR(tstLocal) = '2014' AND MONTH(tstLocal) = '7'
GROUP BY YEAR(tstLocal), MONTH(tstLocal),  DAY(tstLocal);
```

Comment: Very nice, +1. Just like in the old times without subselects :-)

Comment: Beautiful, very nice as well. Thx for that.