# Mysql error on group_concat

Tags: mysql

I posted  [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841595/daily-datetime-of-min-max-in-same-row-in-an-adjacent-column/26790257#26790257)
but I should have posted a new

I am beginner on MySQL
I tried exampleon link  above but get some error codes

MY select looks like this

```
SELECT YEAR(TimeStamp) AS "YEAR", MONTHNAME(TimeStamp) AS "MONTH", DAY(TimeStamp) AS "DAY",
       min(Temperature) AS "min", max(Temperature) AS "max",
       ROUND(AVG(Temperature),1) AS "avg",
       substring_index(group_concat(TimeStamp order by Temperature asc), ',', 1) as min_TimeStamp,
       substring_index(group_concat(TimeStamp order by Temperature desc), ',', 1) as max_TimeStamp
FROM ute_temp_min
    WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2014-11-05' and NOW()
GROUP BY YEAR(TimeStamp), MONTH(TimeStamp),  DAY(TimeStamp);
```

this is my input table

```
index","TimeStamp","Temperature"
2721909,"2014-11-05 00:00:08",1.4
2721910,"2014-11-05 00:01:12",1.4
2721911,"2014-11-05 00:02:13",1.4
2721912,"2014-11-05 00:03:06",1.4
```

this is my output  and it looks at it's OK

```
"YEAR","MONTH","DAY","min","max","avg","min_TimeStamp","max_TimeStamp"
2014,"November",5,-3.4,1.4,-0.6,"2014-11-05 22:15:16","2014-11-05 00:28:12"
2014,"November",6,-2.6,0.3,-0.9,"2014-11-06 01:34:08","2014-11-06 12:52:12"
```

But I get this error (more of them but same but different rows

```
Row 52 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT() errornr 1260
```

What is my mistake?

Sven Åke

Comment: You need to set the group concat max len http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: To a rough approximation, I'm not convinced that there is any problem for which GROUP_CONCAT is (part of) the solution.

Comment: if I delete  2 lines with substrings I get no errors

Answer (score 1):

try setting your session max length. I have been using it all week to fix a data integrity issue on our servers so group concat is very useful for that (to visually see users that shouldn't be linked together) but i too had an issue with data getting cut off

try this

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 999999999;
SELECT ... -- your query here
```

the awesome thing about this is its only in your **current session** (its a temporary function).. so you aren't allocating memory on the server(disk space) so it wont slow things down any. the length is changed back to its default value (1024) after your session ends!

#### EDIT:

a little cleanup on the query you have

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(TimeStamp) AS "YEAR", 
    MONTHNAME(TimeStamp) AS "MONTH", 
    DAY(TimeStamp) AS "DAY",
    min(Temperature) AS "min", 
    max(Temperature) AS "max",
    ROUND(AVG(Temperature),1) AS "avg",
    substring_index(group_concat(TimeStamp order by Temperature asc), ',', 1) as min_TimeStamp,
    substring_index(group_concat(TimeStamp order by Temperature desc), ',', 1) as max_TimeStamp
FROM ute_temp_min
WHERE DATE(TimeStamp) BETWEEN '2014-11-05' and CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(TimeStamp);
```

notice I changed the `WHERE` to do a date comparison (so MySQL isn't having to convert your string date to a datetime by itself) 
I also changed the `GROUP BY` to be on DATE() to do less calculations

Comment: I pasted John Ruddell's hole select but still same error

Comment: @zacken542 did you execute the first query and then your select? aka `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 9999999;` first and then the SELECT after?

Comment: sorry did not understand that I needed both, NOW it's Working.THANKS

Comment: @zacken542 yea sorry I was trying to specify that! if you could mark the answer as accepted I would really appreciate it! :) i'll throw you a +1 too